# Lots of CPU time on Task.ContinueWith?

Tags: .net, profiling, cpu-usage, perfview

I'm CPU profiling a .NET Framework WebServer using PerfView and I noticed a lot of CPU time directly on `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ContinueWith`.
What does it mean? Should I worry about it?

```
Name  OTHER <<mscorlib.ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.__Canon].ContinueWith[System.__Canon](System.Func`2,System.__Canon>)>>        
Exc % 10.0     
Exc   1,539  
Inc % 10.0     
Inc   1,539
```

Comment: Is it definitely that function and not something in the subtree? Are you awaiting something in a very tight loop?

Comment: Unfortunately Perfview didn't report anything on the subtree. This code was on a Nuget package - I decompiled it and explored the misterious stack. Turns out it seems there was lots of things being done on a `Task.ContinueWith` - I changed the code to cache the calls to this lib and then I got a performance gain! Looking to remove this lib in the future